# Duplicate images in my assets.car

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

So I was snooping around in that achieve trying to make my app smaller.  And I found something odd!

There are two identical copies of every image! One with an ending "~iPad" and one with "~iPad@2x"

I understand the purpose of having those two endings, but when I am setting up the .xcassets the way I am.... I don't expect the app to need it.  Is there any way to get rid of the duplicate?

Here is how I have set up one of my entires:
[image]

Comment: what you want exactly?

Comment: I want to optimize the size of the app store download.  Ideally that would mean that their weren't two of each image with no differences except their names.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `universal` image asset instead of separate for `iphone` and `ipad`.

from `assets` select this image set and from `attribute inspector` uncheck iphone and ipad under `Device` and `check universal` from it.

So you will get universal imageset with 1x,2x and 3x will automatically used by iphone and ipad both.

If you are using different size of images for iphone and ipad then you must set separate images for iphone and ipad but if you are using same image size then you should use `universal` as i mentioned above.

Hope this will help :)